# Is there a one line code for converting a flat list to a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I only know this below. I wonder if there is a shorter coding for it.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = []
for i in a:
    b.append([i])
```

output: b = [[1],[2],[3]]

Comment: `b = [[i] for i in a]`— see [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code;

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[i] for i in a]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehension suggested by @khelwood is an efficient approach in this case as it doesn’t make use of extra space.

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [[e] for e in a]
print(b)
```

Another option would be:

```
b = list(map(lambda e:[e], a))
print(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

`b=[[i] for i in [1,2,3]]` is the one-liner you are looking for.